# Person Age Virtual Property in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to know if there is a simple way in Mongoose of getting a person's age from the associated birthdate in the schema.

```
// Define the User schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    first_name: { type: String, required: true, max: [15, 'Too long name'] },
    last_name: { type: String, required: true, max: [15, 'Too long surname'] },
    gender: { type: String, required: true, enum: ['M', 'F'] },
    image: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
    birthdate: { type: Date, required: true }
}, {
    collection: 'Users'
});
```

How to implement this?

```
// Virtual for user's age
UserSchema
.virtual('age')
.get(function() {
...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the date like bellow :

**Short answer :**

```js
const birthdate = new Date(687882497000);

// replace birthdate by this.birthdate
const nbYearRounded = Math.floor((Date.now() - birthdate.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365));

console.log(nbYearRounded);
```

---

**Exxplaination** :

```js
const date = new Date(687882497000);

const timeInMs = date.getTime();

const diffInMs = Date.now() - timeInMs;

const nbDay = diffInMs / 1000 / 3600 / 24;

const nbYear = nbDay / 365;

const nbYearRounded = Math.floor(nbYear);

console.log(date);
console.log(timeInMs);
console.log(diffInMs);
console.log(nbDay);
console.log(nbYear);
console.log(nbYearRounded);
```

---

[Here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#virtualtype_VirtualType-get) is the documentation about *VirtualType.prototype.get()*.

Given example :

```
var virtual = schema.virtual('fullname');
virtual.get(function () {
  return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
UserSchema.virtual('age').get(function(){
    return Math.floor((Date.now() - this.birthdate.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365));
});
```